# Echo different result depending on the value selected php

Tags: php, loops, selected

I have 2 tables in the database one is called `productBrands` and the other `products`.

Now i want to echo out the result of the Products depending on what brand I have selected.

I got the basics to work but im not sure how to test what brand is selected.

```
        echo '
           Brand:<br><select name="brand">';

        $brandsQuery = "SELECT * FROM productBrands";
        $brands  = mysql_query($brandsQuery) or
        die("SQL: $brandsQuery)<br />".mysql_error());

        $brandsNo = mysql_num_rows($brands);
        echo '<option value="" selected>Choose a brand...</option>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $brandsNo; $i++) {
            $name       = mysql_result($brands, $i, 'name');
            $brandid         = mysql_result($brands, $i, 'id');

            echo '<option value="' . $brandid . '">' . $name . '</option>';
        }

        echo '</select><br/>';


        echo 'Produkt:<br><select name="produkt">';

                   $productsQuery = "SELECT * FROM products";
                   $products  = mysql_query($productsQuery) or
                   die("SQL: $productsQuery)<br />".mysql_error());

                   $productsNo = mysql_num_rows($products);     
                   $brandQuery = "SELECT productBrand from products";                       
                   for ($f = 0; $f < $productsNo; $f++ ) {
                       $productName = mysql_result($products, $f, 'productName');
                       $productId = mysql_result($products, $f, 'productId');

                       echo '<option value="' .$productId .'">' . $productName .'</option>';}
                   echo '</select><br/>';
```

This prints out the correct values but it doesn't take in what first  is selected.

Comment: So just to understand how you expect the user to interact with this...  You expect to display a dropdown with brands in it.  The user selects a brand and then the products in that brand are supposed to populate below?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
$brandsQuery = "SELECT * FROM productBrands";
```

to this:

```
$brandsQuery = sprintf("SELECT * FROM productBrands WHERE brandname = '%s'", 
                                           mysql_real_escape_string($brand));
```

This will insert the brand that you asked the user for, and will not produce all results, only the products related to the brand specified.

Note: The above assumes that you got the `$brand` value from the dropbox you mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this is a part of a form (or some filter that is submitted) and You are using POST to submit a form, You have to extend the second part of the script:

```
echo 'Produkt:<br><select name="produkt">';
$whereBrand = '';
if(isset($_POST['brand']) $where = " WHERE productBrand = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['brand'])."'";
$productsQuery = "SELECT * FROM products{$whereBrand}";
$products  = mysql_query($productsQuery) or
    die("SQL: $productsQuery)<br />".mysql_error());

$productsNo = mysql_num_rows($products); 
for ($f = 0; $f < $productsNo; $f++ ) {
    $productName = mysql_result($products, $f, 'productName');
    $productId = mysql_result($products, $f, 'productId');

    echo '<option value="' .$productId .'">' . $productName .'</option>';
}
echo '</select><br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three common ways to handle this.

1) Write this as a form and post back the selected value.  Remember that PHP is server-side only, so the server is unaware of what the user does on the page.

2) Use jQuery or some other means of performing an AJAX callback to another action on the server when the brand is selected.  The result of this callback is the information that you want to fill in for the rest of the page.

3) If the dataset is relatively small, you can have all of the data loaded into the page, as a javascript array, and then handle the rest in javascript on the page.

Option #2 is probably your best bet, all around.
Option #1 is likely to be easier for a beginner to implement, however.
Only use option #3 if the data set is relatively small.